# CSRF on spring cloud gateway removing formData from POST requests 400 bad request error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I have enabled CSRF on my spring cloud api gateway server.
I have angular as my GUI framework which calls the rest services through the api gateway.

I have used a custom filter to add the CSRF token to the response headers.

When the POST call is made I see that the formData is lost. So I always get 400 Bad request errors.

I disabled CSRF and the request goes through fine without any issues.

Is there something wrong?

Below is my spring cloud gateway configuration. Gateway is used only for routing the requests to other microservices, it does not have any controllers or rest endpoints.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

@Autowired
ProfileManager profileManager;

@PostConstruct
public void onInit() {
    profileManager.printActiveProfiles();
}

public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args); }
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll();
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    return http.build();
   }
}
```

below is the filter code

```
@Component
public class CsrfHeaderFilter implements WebFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    Mono<CsrfToken> token = (Mono<CsrfToken>) exchange.getAttributes().get(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (token != null) {
        return token.flatMap(t -> chain.filter(exchange));
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

}

My POST rest endpoints are defined with

> @RequestParam

below is the code from one of the rest service endpoints. It is an upstream service implemented using the traditional servlet springboot framework.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "terminate/{listName}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@CrossOrigin
@Loggable (activityname = ActivityLogConstants.DESCRIPTOR_TERMINATE)
public Response terminate(@Context HttpServletRequest reqContext, @PathVariable String listName, @RequestParam(value = "rowData") String rowData)
        throws ServiceException {....}
```

The formData is lost by the time the request reaches the upstream services.

Looks like the filter in spring cloud gateways is blocking formData

here is my netty configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class NettyConfiguration implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

@Value("${server.max-initial-line-length:65536}")
private int maxInitialLingLength;
@Value("${server.max-http-header-size:65536}")
private int maxHttpHeaderSize;

public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory container) {
    container.addServerCustomizers(
            httpServer -> httpServer.httpRequestDecoder(
                    httpRequestDecoderSpec -> {
                        httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxHeaderSize(maxHttpHeaderSize);
                        httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxInitialLineLength(maxInitialLingLength);
                        return httpRequestDecoderSpec;
                    }
            )
    );
}
}
```

below is my application.yml
[image]

sample log:

> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.743 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id:199cd714-5, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] Received response (auto-read:false) : [X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma=no-cache, Expires=0, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains, X-Frame-Options=DENY, X-Application-Context=application:18080, Date=Thu, 28 Jul 2022 03:48:20 GMT, Connection=close, content-length=0]
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.744 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider    : [id:199cd714-5, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] onStateChange(POST{uri=/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]}}, [response_received])
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.744 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id:199cd714-5, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.744 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations     : [id:199cd714-5, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] Received last HTTP packet
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.744 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id:b0f975eb-11, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id:b0f975eb-11, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [b0f975eb-11, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] **Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST**
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id:b0f975eb-11, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] Last HTTP response frame
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] c.m.webgateway.handler.RequestLogger     : Total time required to process /cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor request 60055
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider    : [id:199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] onStateChange(POST{uri=/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]}}, [response_completed])
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.745 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider    : [id:199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] onStateChange(POST{uri=/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor, connection=PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]}}, [disconnecting])
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.752 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id:199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] Channel closed, now: 0 active connections, 4 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
> 2022-07-28 09:18:20.752 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider    : [id:199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x199cd714, L:/127.0.0.1:50342 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]}, [disconnecting])
> 2022-07-28 09:18:23.805 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id:b0f975eb, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] Increasing pending responses, now 1
> 2022-07-28 09:18:23.805 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id:b0f975eb-12, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@7c82616c
> 2022-07-28 09:18:23.805 DEBUG 26532 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [b0f975eb-12, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50337] HTTP GET "/cms-service/webapi/data/descriptor"

below is the link to the sample project.
https://github.com/manjosh1990/webgateway-issues

I tried to ignore FORM URL ENCODED requests and GET request, but it still does not work

```
private static final Set<HttpMethod> ALLOWED_METHODS = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.HEAD, HttpMethod.TRACE, HttpMethod.OPTIONS));
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and()
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(ignoringFormUrlEncodedContentType())
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));
    return http.build();
}
private ServerWebExchangeMatcher ignoringFormUrlEncodedContentType() {
    return (exchange) -> !MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.isCompatibleWith(
            exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType()) || !ALLOWED_METHODS.contains(exchange.getRequest().getMethod())
            ? ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match()
            : ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch();
}
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Gateway is built on the reactive support of Spring WebFlux, but your example controller method looks to be using servlets. In reactive applications, you access a `ServerWebExchange` instead of `HttpServlet*`. See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux).

Comment: Also, the custom filter you provided doesn't seem to be writing the header to the response, only adding it to the reactive stream so that it can be subscribed to, is that intentional?

Comment: The controller is actually my rest service based on servlets, routes are configured to forward the request from gateway to the rest service. For custom filter, after following CSRF for webflux I was not able to get the CSRF token in the session, so following this article and it worked https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6046

Comment: Gotcha. Glad it's working for you!

Comment: I mean I followed that GitHub discussion thread were they had implemented the custom csrfHeader filter. That’s were Mono<CsrfToken> is added to the stream. After this change it adds the CSRF token to the header. But for POST requests, I lose the formData, this is the problem that I’m facing

Comment: I see. So you're using Spring Security in your Spring Cloud Gateway but your POST endpoint is in another service behind the gateway. Does that service use Spring Security as well? Can you provide any debug information or minimal sample? There could be several places where this is going wrong, including in the custom filter.

Comment: I have attached the sample log and configuration file. You can check the full log here https://github.com/manjosh1990/webgateway-issues

Comment: And the rest service does not have spring security, it's only the Spring cloud gateway that has spring security enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the logs, I'm not sure I see anything specific, but the logs do bring more questions to mind that it might be difficult to hash out. I'm not sure I can identify the issue short of a minimal sample that reproduces the issue. Can you provide one?

Comment: I have added the sample project here https://github.com/manjosh1990/webgateway-issues

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was out last week. I added an answer though it's really more of "I think you found a bug!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the minimal sample to reproduce the issue!

After some testing, I'm unable to come up with a workaround or fix for your configuration that allows a form post (URL-encoded) to pass through the gateway with CSRF protection enabled. My best guess is it has to do with how Spring Security is consuming the request body (which should be cached for subsequent filters to consume) vs how Spring Cloud Gateway is consuming the request body in order to proxy to the downstream service.

I tested this by disabling CSRF protection and adding the following filter:

```java
@Component
public class TestWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> exchange.getFormData()
                .doOnSuccess(System.out::println))
                .then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }
}
```

In my testing, this causes the request through the gateway to block for a long time before receiving:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-10T19:13:54.265+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/cms-service/webapi/service/post/test"
}
```

Since this appears to be a bug in Spring Security, I'd recommend submitting a bug in Spring Security and we can work through it from there.

If you would like to work around the issue in the meantime, you can disable CSRF protection for these types of requests, as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(ignoringFormUrlEncodedContentType())
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerWebExchangeMatcher ignoringFormUrlEncodedContentType() {
        return (exchange) -> !MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.isCompatibleWith(
            exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType())
                ? ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match()
                : ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch();
    }

}
```

**Important:** This is not ideal, because these requests won't be protected. However, this might make sense if these requests were never performed in a browser. In that case, it would make sense to have a separate authentication mechanism, such as requiring a bearer token instead of form login, etc. (as in the example above).

Comment: thank you, here is the bug : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11687

Comment: Gotcha. I had forgotten that you had opened a bug at the same/similar time as posting this question. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to disable CSRF for APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED request, but now I get "Invalid CSRF token" even for GET requests. I have pushed the changes to the repository, can you have a look.

Comment: You're right, the example above would cause that issue for GET requests. It was just an example of disabling it for Form Data requests. You would want to combine the above matcher with normal CSRF protection matching, which also ignores GET, HEAD, TRACE and OPTIONS. See [CsrfWebFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/009032e03cdf79e60879663810d63d8069a87a96/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/csrf/CsrfWebFilter.java#L197-L209).

Comment: I tried to allow GET requests as well, but I still get "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" .Im not sure what mistake I am doing. Could you please help.

Comment: I believe your logic is incorrect in the sample ([here](https://github.com/manjosh1990/webgateway-issues)). I've added a comment to the commit.

Comment: thanks, but I could not find the comment.

Comment: https://github.com/manjosh1990/webgateway-issues/commit/12d7468b1711c1faf5cff31980fcd4e75ce2ae17#r86355425

Comment: Thanks, It is working for me now. Will continue testing this fix and report if any issues.